# How can I define policies for my API for two types of access tokens, one with an identity (sub) and one without?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, api-authorization, policy-server

I am using IdentityServer4 via ASPNET Core, and I want users to access my API both by the web browser via their identity (Implicit and Hybrid), and by clients programatically (Client Credentials). I realize all I have to do is add `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` and I am done. However, that only solves the authentication aspect of this problem, not the authorization.

#### Authorization:

With ASPNET Core, you can just use Role based auth (or PolicyServer permissions which is similar) but only if you have an identity with role claims, that **does not** work for client credentials. So that brings us to needing to secure by role, or policies AND by scopes. How can I do this?

- You cant have multiple policies, if you do, they both must pass.
- You can't have multiple auth schemes, because my call to `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` will have to use the same authority, so how would IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/JwtBearer know which you scheme challenge you are trying to pass?
- Multiple requirements could work, but you need to add extra requirements on the condition that you are dealing with a non-identity access token. How can you detect what type of token you are dealing with? **Is it safe to just say "If no sub, this is client creds."**
- Should I scrap this design and force device code flow on my users? Look at `az cli` it magically opens a browser, and then you can start scripting away to your hearts content. IS4 supports this with ease, especially with `verficationUrlComplete`

I think I have a working POC, but I am far from happy with it. https://gist.github.com/VictorioBerra/8c333a228c55d86a7c15f7f300284634

It involves basically re-implementing the default scope claim requirement handler and policyservers permission requirement handler. But thats the only way to conditionally apply the requirement handlers based on the token type.

Comment: Good question, but I am struggling to understand why you need the “sub” claim in your context?

Comment: Its just an indicator that you are dealing with an identity. So, without it you basically have to resort to doing regular scope authz. api1, and api.read_only, and api1.admin. A token from implicit or hybrid auth cant use that __because everyone shares the same client__ so we need some way to say "if this token is identity, check roles, or whatever else we need, otherwise, start checking scopes."

Comment: Yeah, but you can have role claim in client credentials. That’s why I asked why you need “sub” claim because I thought you might have overlooked that.

Comment: How do you add a role claim to client credentials? When I think of roles i think of them as being populated from like Active Directory. We use AdminUI for our front-end to IS4 and i dont see a way even to hardcode claims like I can with other grant types.

Comment: Actually i see that now in AdminUI I must have missed it before somehow... I think this might just work

Comment: It can come from your ConfigurationStore for example. And it does work, I have implemented it like that in some projects. You could also create a new flow where all client_credentials_custom would have “sub” claim (think of it as service accounts). Basically, there are many ways to tackle your issue, so don’t give up!

Comment: Thanks a lot this is was very helpful. I find it very hard to get help with this subject its such a niche topic, you have to know where to find the community.

Comment: You are very much welcome, I added the info as an answer in case someone else stumbles upon a similar question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways of how to go around your problem of implementing role based authentication:

- You might have misunderstood the fact that a client can have `role` claims in the `client_credentials` flow.
- You could even have `sub` claim if you implemented `client_credentials_custom` flow and essentially bind a client to a particular user account (think of this as a service account)

Comment: I was wondering if you could elaborate on `client_creds_custom` flow. You say this adds a sub basically, how do you go about doing that? Whats the flow look like?

Comment: @VictorioBerra Think of it as and impersonation flow, so each oauth client could be bound to a user id (dynamically or not, it’s up to you). So whenever you use this flow, you would get extra claims based on this bound user account. The flow would be identical to client credentials except the grant type would be client_credentials_custom or w/e name you like

Comment: So, I know you can just add a hard coded "sub" to the claims of any client. Why would one need a custom grant type instead of just having the sub attached to the client at registration time?